# How to format the output in one line in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
print(df[['imdb_score','movie_title', 'gross', 'content_rating','genres']].nlargest(3, 'imdb_score'))
```

Here's my code that prints out these listed columns and is sorted by top 3 highest values in 'imdb_score'

[Here's how the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rELTY.png)

How can I make format it in a way to look like this, with one line each and is neat?:

Rank 96: Interstellar, $187991439, PG-13, Adventure|Drama|Sci-Fi

Rank 296: Django Unchained, $162804648,  R,  Drama|Western

Rank 10: Dawn of Justice, $330249062, PG-13, Adventure|Drama|Sci-Fi

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ['imdb_score', 'movie_title',
        'gross', 'content_rating','genres']
df.loc[df.imdb_score.nlargest(3).index, cols]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I need!

Comment: @Py-not-good don't forget to accept the answer and up vote. Thanks and glad I could help.